# How do I control the author and date text in the title-slide in xaringan slides rmarkdown with a css file

Tags: css, r-markdown, remarkjs, xaringan

I want to control the author and date text in xaringan rmarkdown with a css file?

I tried with

```
.title-slide h3 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: grey;
  background-color: white; }
```

But apparently this control both, the author and date together, but they stay on top of each other (at the same position).

Answer (score 12):

By default, the author is the first `h3`, and the date is the second `h3`, so you can use the [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) `nth-of-type` on the title slide, e.g., color the author to red, and date to gray:

```
.title-slide h3:nth-of-type(1) {
    color: red;
}
.title-slide h3:nth-of-type(2) {
    color: gray;
}
```

Comment: @ManuelSpínola Please accept the answer is it works.